# Ignoring child properties on serializing to JSON

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialize a parent class only object properties.
Assume i have a class:

```
public class Parent{...some props...}
public class Child extends Parent{..some child props...}
```

Now having an object of Child type:

```
Child obj = new Child();
```

Id like to store/serialize only the Parent object instead:

```
StoreToMongo((Parent)obj);
```

Since an object of Child type it still stores a complete Child object, instead of Parent.

Any workaround or just a deep copying into a new object of Parent type and storing it?

Comment: You can make the child class properties **`transient`**. This way `only parent class properties` will be serialized!

Comment: No i cant, a thing is in some cases i need to store it as Parent, in some as Child, but a complete object structure in the DB needs to be Child.

Comment: An option i was thinking about is to make Child(bigger class) to be a parent  with child (currently Parent) extend from the bigger ones and hide unnecessary properties, but its looks quite ugly and does not fit in OOD.